# How to fetch and display data while scrolling the page using php mysqli javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM postadds ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 12";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<hr><center><h3>". $row["addtitle"]. "</h3><small>" . $row["short_description"] ."</small></center><br>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I have the above code to display 12 data from `mysql` using `php`.
And what I want to know is, how to auto load more data from `database` to display while user can `scroll` the page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: read about ajax, and run ajax request when user scroll to the bottom

Comment: Daimos Thank you .. let me try with ajax.

Comment: @Karthick see this link, i think your searching for this.http://demos.thesoftwareguy.in/ajax-scroll-down-pagination/

Comment: yes u right niranjan ... thank you for the link. let me try with my datas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jScroll is a good option for you right now, it will allow you to implement this functionality without knowing a lot in jQuery / Ajax.

Just download / import the script for [the official website](http://jscroll.com/), a quick look at the documentation will show you how to implement it, but here's a short description :

```
$('.scroll').jscroll();

<div class="scroll">
    <h2>Page number x</h2>
    <?php
        // Count if you have more page to show with your SQL query
        $isLast = yourMagicFunction();

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<hr><center><h3>". $row["addtitle"]. "</h3><small>" . $row["short_description"] ."</small></center><br>";
        } else {
            echo "Nothing more";
        }

        if($isLast) echo '<a href="next.html">Next page</a>';
     ?>
</div>
```

While you have a link in your scroll div, the script will load the content displayed on the existing link, and it will automatically stop once the div no more contain a link.